# WSO2 Oracle DDL script uses Varchar and not Varchar2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, wso2, wso2-api-manager, ddl

We are looking to use WSO2 API manager at our current client, and are required to use the provided Oracle DDL to set up the necessary tables for Carbon, API manager and message broker.  The Client's dba's are coming back asking why the script uses varchar instead of Varchar2 for the relevant fields, which is a good question as the standard approach for oracle is "Varchar2 is the industry standard, don't use varchar."

Is there a really good reason why the oracle scripts use Varchar instead of Varchar2?  When implemented on top of Oracle, what is WSO2 doing that required the ability to differentiate null from empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was probably a simple typo that doesn't matter.

It looks like only the column `AM_API.INDEXER` uses `VARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR2`.  The program also contains scripts for H2, MS SQL, MySQL, and PostGreSQL.  All the other databases use VARCHAR.  This is a pretty common mistake for products that support multiple databases.

Keep in mind that there is no meaningful difference between `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2` in Oracle.  The documentation *claims* that someday there will be a difference but I highly doubt it.  This issue has existed for a long time and there's a ton of legacy code that depends on the old behavior.  I would bet good money that Oracle will never make `VARCHAR` use different `NULL` comparison semantics.

I tried to change the script and created a [pull request](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/4009).  I don't understand this project and almost certainly did something wrong.  So don't be surprised if the request is rejected.  But perhaps it will in some way help to lead toward a fix.

Comment: Thanks @jon I thought it was likely something like that, but thought there may have been deliberate choice in this.  Hopefully the changes get accepted, it would be a confirmation that it was an oversight.